# how to limit the duplicate to 5 in pandas data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

```
col1= ['A','B','A','C','A','B','A','C','A','C','A','A','A']
col2= [1,1,4,2,4,5,6,3,1,5,2,1,1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1, 'col2':col2})
```

for A we have `[1,4,4,6,1,2,1,1]`, 8 items but i want to limit the size to 5 while converting Data frame to dict/list

Output:

```
Dict = {'A':[1,4,4,6,1],'B':[1,5],'C':[2,3,5]}
```

Comment: How does your original `df` look like?

Comment: sorry because of some error i did not put the original df. but now its updated.

Answer (score 7):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `apply`:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x:list(x.head(5))).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'A': [1, 4, 4, 6, 1], 'B': [1, 5], 'C': [2, 3, 5]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function, convert to list and filter first 5 values by indexing, last convert to dictionary by [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()[:5]).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': [1, 4, 4, 6, 1], 'B': [1, 5], 'C': [2, 3, 5]}
```